# Why is my interpolated map seemingly in the wrong position relative to the points?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a surface based on these points but the output map looks like it's offset. I can't figure out why. They both have the same CRS WGS84 4326.[image]

Comment: Hi kvis, There is not enough information to know what is the problem. Please, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/353586/edit) your question to include: - the QGIS version used (About screenshot); - the command and parameters used for the interpolation (screenshot of the processing GUI); - also screenshots of the General properties of each layer.